# Error while building Classification Tree in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree

This is a code which i found in scikit learn website

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
iris = load_iris()
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

here what is (iris.data,iris.target), 
for my project purpose using this code i've modified like
   `pest=open("project.csv","r+")`

```
clf=clf.fit(pest.data,pest.target)
```

but i get an error file has no attribute "data". 
[please click on this to view my data set "project"](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7J0TzMJ1It7ZHNaTHFQSXh5ams/edit).

I need to get a tree which has the root node crops and the leaf nodes toxicity level. How can I set the root node and the class label. I've tried a lot but could not get it.

Comment: export your data into an csv file or other pure text format first.

Comment: @greeness I've done that. I saved the file in .csv format... Can u help how to set which part of the file is data and which is target?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that your pest only contains your file content. You should probably add a step where you select which part of the file is the data and which is the target.

Comment: I don't know how to read from an excel file, you should probably google and find a tutorial on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you only open the .csv file, and you don't load anything from it. You need to load the data and specify which column is 'data' and which column is 'target'. [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) are some sample codes for loading data from csv files.